# jquery and jscript (form validation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm writing a code to validate a password though I'm little confused with jquery and jscript.

This is my function:

```
function validatePassword(){
    var symbols = "!"; 
    var password0 = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if(password0.includes(symbols)){

        window.alert("sorry");
    }
    else{
        window.alert("good job!");
    }    }
```

The code runs perfectly when:

```
document.getElementById("register").onclick = function() { validatePassword(); };
```

However it's not running when:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
        'placement': 'top',
    });

    $('#register').click(function() {
        ('#password').validatePassword();
    });
    }); });
```

can anyone explain why?

Comment: That's not a jQuery method, and you don't want to make it one.

Comment: Take a closer look at what this is doing `('#password').` its not using `$` and not selecting any element. But why do you need to call it like this if it works the other way? Just use `$('#register').click(function() { validatePassword(); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are looking for is

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
        'placement': 'top',
    });

    $('#register').click(validatePassword);
});
```

You meant to type `$('#password').validatePassword()`, but that also would not work - the element with ID "password" does not have a property `validatePassword`.  It's just a function that you can call by name.

As a fun fact, because validatePassword is stored as a global variable, it's actually stored in `window`. So, `$('#register').click(validatePassword)` and `$('#register').click(window.validatePassword)` would both work.